# How to correctly implement customized password reset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I got the following error when i ran the `python manage.py makemigrations` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/remittance_platform/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/remittance_platform/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/remittance_platform/remittance_platform/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('', include('remittance.urls')),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/remittance_platform/remittance/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/remittance_platform/remittance/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .forms import TransactionForm
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/remittance_platform/remittance/forms.py", line 40, in <module>
    class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/edward/Desktop/Lynia-remittance-platform-/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 321, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for User
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class RemittanceUser(AbstractUser):
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password',
                                   help_text='<ul><li>Your password must be at least 8 characters long.</li>'
                                               '<li>Your password must contain at least one uppercase letter.</li>'
                                               '<li>Your password must contain at least one lowercase letter.</li>'
                                               '<li>Your password must contain at least one number.</li>'
                                               '<li>Your password must contain at least one special character.</li></ul>')
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password confirmation',
                                   help_text='Enter the same password as above, for verification.')`
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from remittance.models import Transaction
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from remittance.models import Transaction

class CreateTransactionForm(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    recipient = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    currency = forms.CharField(max_length=3)

class TransactionHistoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'currency', 'status']

class TransactionStatusForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['transaction_status']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['transaction_status'].choices = [
            ('initiated', 'Initiated'),
            ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
            ('completed', 'Completed'),
            ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
        ]

        
class UpdateTransactionStatusForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['status']

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid username or password.')

        self.user = user
        return self.cleaned_data
    

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists.')

        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email address already exists.')

        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        new_password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        new_password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

        if new_password1 != new_password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')

        return new_password2
    
class ForgotPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email address not found.')

        return email
    
class ResetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_new_password2(self):
        new_password1 = self.cleaned_data['new_password1']
        new_password2 = self.cleaned_data['new_password2']

        if new_password1 != new_password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')

        return new_password2
    
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'currency', 'status']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from remittance.models import Transaction
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from remittance.models import Transaction
from .forms import TransactionForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'remittance/home.html', {
        'transactions': transactions,
    })

def create_transaction(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form data from the request
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST)

        # Validate the form data
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new transaction
            transaction = form.save()

            # Redirect the user to the home page
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        # The form hasn't been submitted yet, so show it to the user
        form = TransactionForm()

    return render(request, 'remittance/create_transaction.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

def transaction_history(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    transactions = user.transactions.all()
    return render(request, 'remittance/transaction_history.html', {
        'transactions': transactions,
    })

def update_transaction_status(request, transaction_id):
    transaction = Transaction.objects.get(id=transaction_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form data from the request
        form = TransactionStatusForm(request.POST, instance=transaction)

        # Validate the form data
        if form.is_valid():
            # Update the status of the transaction
            form.save()

            # Redirect the user to the home page
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        # The form hasn't been submitted yet, so show it to the user
        form = TransactionStatusForm(instance=transaction)

    return render(request, 'remittance/update_transaction_status.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the username and password from the request
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        # Authenticate the user
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        # If the user is authenticated, log them in
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            # The username or password is incorrect
            error_message = 'Invalid username or password.'
            return render(request, 'remittance/login.html', {
                'error_message': error_message,
            })
    else:
        # The user hasn't submitted the login form yet, so show it to them
        return render(request, 'remittance/login.html')

def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form data from the request
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        # Validate the form data
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user
            user = form.save()

            # Log the user in
            login(request, user)

            # Redirect the user to the home page
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        # The form hasn't been submitted yet, so show it to the user
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'remittance/register.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('create-transaction/', views.create_transaction, name='create_transaction'),
    path('transaction_history/', views.transaction_history, name='transaction_history'),
    #path('transaction-history/<int:user_id>/', views.transaction_history, name='transaction_history'),
    path('update-transaction-status/', views.update_transaction_status, name='update_transaction_status'),
    #path('update-transaction-status/<int:transaction_id>/', views.update_transaction_status, name='update_transaction_status'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

these are codes and they return the error: **Unknown field(s) (password1, password2) specified for User** when I run the `python manage.py makemigrations` command.

I have customized the user model and named it `RemittanceUser`, which inherits from `AbstractUser`. Within my `RemittanceUser` model, I have defined the `password1` and `password2` fields. However, it seems that Django is unable to locate these fields.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of Error:**

As the traceback shows, is that you are using the `User` model in `RegisterForm`:

```py
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User    # Here you are using the User model for the RegisterForm
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']
```

But, your `User` model doesn't have the fields `new_password1` and `new_password2`.

Instead it has `username`, `email`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `phone_number`.

```py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**Solution**
The default `User` model already has nearly all you want already. If all you want to do is add `phone_number` to it, one way is to create another class, a profile, and do a `OneToOneField` connecting it to the default `User` model as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), or perhaps better, use your custom user model, and set it up similar to how is shown in the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) already given.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you should call the customized user model. Fllow these steps:

1. In your `settings.py` file add the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` variable:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.UserModelName'
```

for example:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'
```

2. Run these commands:

```
>>> python manage.py makemigrations
>>> python manage.py migrate
>>> python manage.py runserver
```

3. import the user model in `forms.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

4. now, you can use a form class to your customized user model:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']
```